# Case when rowcount

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, rowcount

```
 SELECT distinct ID from table
```

Result

```
    Letter
1   A
2   B
```

How can I make the select display the following when the result is as above:

What I was thinking but not working yet:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT(ID) = 2 THEN 'AB'
ELSE ID END AS ID
FROM table
```

Result would be

```
     Letter
1    AB
```

Comment: And if the result ha 3 records?

Comment: The result will always be null, 1 or 2 records in my example

Comment: Please show the headers and content of table as well as the headers of the results.

Comment: [@@ROWCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) can not be used like this. What you need is `ROW_NUMBER()` if I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Select
  CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID])) = 2 THEN 'AB'
  ELSE [ID] END AS [ID]
FROM table
group by
  [ID]
```

What's above will also only work if [ID] and 'AB' are the same data type.  If not, then you'll need to cast [ID] to a varchar in your ELSE statement.  That'd be: `ELSE cast([ID] as varchar(8)) END AS [ID]`

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements really aren't clear.

Based on various assumptions, this *might* give you what you want.

```
SELECT Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 937)
     , CASE WHEN Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 937) = 2 THEN
         'AB'
       ELSE
         id
       END As id
     , id
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you are trying to achieve. But to me it looks like this is what you are trying..

`Declare` a Variable and `initialize` it with `Distinct Count` of `ID` and use it in `select`

```
Declare @cnt int

SELECT @cnt=count(distinct ID) from table

SELECT CASE WHEN @cnt = 2 THEN 'AB'
ELSE ID END AS ID
FROM table
```